# physical storage area of MarkLogic

Tags: database, nosql, marklogic

where does the content of any MarkLogic database store? In my system filesystem, can I see the contents? As per MarkLogic documents, forests hold the contents. but how can I check the contents of database physically?
I am using MarkLogic8 on ubuntu platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MarkLogic forest data is stored where ever specified when the forest was created.  By default it's usually /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests, however the data is not stored in a human readable format.

In the MarkLogic Administrative UI, you can look at the Summary tab under the Forests menu, and look at the 'Data Dir' to determine where the Forests directory is located.[image: MarkLogic Admin Interface]